# powershell - get part of name folder

Tags: powershell

I using powershell and I need to get part of name folder and set it into a variable. For examle I have folder with name "test-123", directory is c:\tmp\test-123 .

I need to set into variable only "-123" and use this for example to insert into .txt file (replace some other text). Is there any way?

Comment: Can you use regex to capture the items after the dash?

Comment: I don't know what you think..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty simple with built-in string manipulation.

```
$FullFolderPath = 'C:\tmp\test-123';

#Depending on PowerShell version, you may need ToString() here.
$FolderName = (Split-Path $FullFolderPath -Leaf).ToString();

#Gets the index of the first dash in the file name.  If you know you
#need the last dash, use LastIndexOf('-') instead.
$DashIndex = $FolderName.IndexOf('-');

#Return a substring from a starting position to the end of the string
$FolderNameFromDashToEnd = $FolderName.SubString($DashIndex);
```

`$FolderNameFromDashToEnd` should now have the value `-123`.

Comment: Thank you, it is great. One more question, if I want replace all line in .txt file (the second line) and the line has always different number (or character) at the end. What will be the syntax?

Comment: @fojtyy I'm not sure offhand.  I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, or exactly what you're looking to do.  I suggest posting another question with more details, sample input, and expected results.

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe:

```
$TestPath = "c:\tmp\test-123";

$TestPath.Split('-') | % { $Wanted = "-" + $_ }

$Wanted
```